# How do I open a gem for editing in RubyMine?

Tags: rubygems, rubymine

Does anyone know how I can use RubyMine to open a gem for editing?

If this is not possible, then how do I set RubyMine as my default editor to open the gem?

Answer (score 4):

On Mac, in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export EDITOR=/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/MacOS/rubymine
```

then `bundle open the-gem`. Adjust to taste for other OSes.

You can also use RubyMine's "Tools -> Create Command line Launcher" to create a launcher script and set `EDITOR` to that.

Alternatively, if the gem you want to browse is part of a RubyMine project, you don't need to bother with `bundle open`: just open External Libraries at the very bottom of the Project tab, find the gem, and browse and edit just as you would your own code.

RubyMine will warn you before allowing you to edit a file in a gem, but will allow you to do so if you insist.

Answer (score 2):

Very often you can just open gem in a project's tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit a gem `GEMNAME`, first you have to get the sources.  Usually you'll find them on github by searching for `github GEMNAME`.

You'll find the git repository name in that little box under SSH clone URL. Just click the icon to put it into your paste buffer.

In your sources directory, lets say `~/src` enter

> git clone git@github.com:AUTHOR/GEMNAME.git

Now you can open the Project in RubyMine File -> Open `~/src/GEMNAME`

After editing you can generate a new gem file with

> gem build GEMNAME.gemspec

which you can install with

> gem install GEMNAME.gem